# How to activate one LED separately in a group of LEDs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, led, resistors, switches

I want to activate one LED in a group of LEDs depending resistance varies linearly depending on the temperature.

I am using variable resistance that Controls how LEDs will light.

LED1 and LED 2 and LED 3 Depends on Variable resistivity

The problem I have encountered with my circuit, all LEDs turn on at the same time.

Maybe the solution is to use the transistors, but I have no information about which type to use them.

Can somebody help?

[[image]

Comment: You need a window comparator for each LED. V>A,<B. Imagine a string of comparators with logic. Or just use a bar graph like a UV display chip

Comment: As requested in your previous and now deleted question, please add the part number and datasheet link for the comparators. The answer depends on this information.

Comment: you have an incomplete voltage divider in your circuit ... add another resistor between top of R4 and Vcc (I am assuming that B1 repesents the input) ... that will turn on LEDs in a bar graph fashion

Comment: [https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) .. @Transistor I used this comparators, But I can use any other type and I am not obligated to use it, can you advise me

Comment: @ jsotola , Unfortunately, it did not work out what you wrote in your comment !! I updated the image.

Comment: You also need a resistor across C1 to set the output voltage created by your current mirror. When you have fixed that, upload a schematic with higher resolution so we see the details.

Comment: It does matter so much what comparator, but rather how to make a cascade window comparator >A AND not > B voltages

Comment: After some effort, this is what works as you imagined.  https://tinyurl.com/yxuca7w9  If you can imagine it, you can synthesize anything.

Comment: No one upvoted my unexpected efforts for a detailed design (free). Shame !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

If you can imagine single supply comparators and CMOS 4xxx series logic on 10V with a 8k pot +4K R to simulate your sensor, [this is it.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0l3AWAnC1b0DYrQIxgMw4YEYIEIDskyFIArJPfZAFABOIpIOFWXYkABxRu8dpwTghE8AkaMcYjvzkywFCAqUz81Hfixa44-hp16jrZZPwGdGYZZM2HMufPANWAczdw3RCKsPJIAtGCSYHRYoWb4AtwggvDYCHIY8JlZdCAACgD2AC4sAO4gsRBggsIVIPh0laXlcQ3lEXWtrGVIWGmMoYqSfVDi4ZHSY56GUsYAls2VE%200CjthwOE0DesNbkdEjZZPx-e31miy%20k%205tQ4HyFwtSNWZg7feHg1M3X2Cjp61XfyMATGACG3Cq3FcKyhwhwOFEIkUWSS0GQ6AxPXo0AaCGSWUy9VEmRY4LwwhBTxm3ARiiRBJAFDRmIxOToOIi%20IJcCJyLEZMhBEWFPiNMRlhSGGZLLQbI5eO58F5WVJEIp-GkYC48PFxMy2PRMpQWHZuK53OVJIFFKxMLAWJ1dIl-gQ0qNSFops5ip5OT5YLVdUF0nicNpHn9-nwbqNwi9Cp9lv5gYMwJDGTFTr1KTAMZlggg8fNBKTxjK5O4vBkPEMTQrMI1jjrgtUKnegfUEFM53LkN0ki4-YOKbsg7sXRTrkH0ObwjOICx84nFeOC6wq%20Xguqa-A283FP2tv2%20-A7Vtb1n3CQEAd1%20HFaIjAdGYnz6fWBwd9fWCiWFte6af9hEXBJv1PSQj1rboPzvc9JDA%20csWGBCEkXTpAL-TDAzAis33vSEsUIn9L1wj9IRPHA0mrKjfmtbg7BhHA7EdCMGSQPMWTjeViyyUsJ21PRtTwbgWAAJWrQTJDMDxVCzeQcWcbgqO1KsnGsGku0kSj4OYKw6gzCtrgrJwAEkqXrbVyOwP0J0Y1pGKo4JiBABBRUM-x6xAAATABTAAzUEAFcABtClCYKfK8xIPBgSANiICBXIgR8XI8jMIF8gKQrCiKooRGLYA2MpGIY6RjJYHA6ARKo4QzVMoQUcBEUUcR6pSoyXz1VqDLvIyvy6yrqu3T8IDau9quapzErc3qPLvDL-KC0Lwsi6KgkKirnKS8DUuBZZvMW7KVryoI1niqrdwpU50vaCa6Rajh6teIZ-Ge%20ljEe9Lt2uGr3uCC7ft%20p7hqa%206ppc0Vfp%207cFqy5bcrW%20S4s26bKn2H79lhpactW-L1uRwbLq%20J79gmrRuuBdHXuPLrPsYVdrg3AaAe3Vd6tXO7yYSiHRoSRmEixo6EbxpH4q20V50Z%20yDrhnGToKgmWbnVp2daTnRCaRjoWG1w9NVxKo06Lqym2wy3JfJpTd6yGLxN83GCtnseZ27bf2HV30chgC7cqb6JdAy3-YdiX0OKyy5wM8jNeGwRIm1WPhwc8Y4XHTXtXs5JuFDqlQyJ3PWDMu1M61SJM-kmzo7nGjB0czXNVezU7jruEE61ptiphwIS-AJvC7K1v450mAK%20K%20vgRhoFm-AfgYa4AuqU5afIjxdaR6JqpgRn9s7UhzUV9smGV%207xf57tLv%20DuayNdHkVfdvxPWeE7vCHOPu5yfwdhPL6%20F6A8AsVsiGJ%20moAEsDfnUauNhHJXxajffS48I7b01I2XcSC5zBirvBaOCgM5wnQuJU2kJtoAJELJGK1kwHmXsunTQMDWBAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, I want to ask you, +VCC and -VCC, what the value did you set on comparators? and what the aim from setting +10v after the LEDs ?

Comment: I chose 10V with 1mA for linear voltage drop with 1V/1k in sensor. You can point at any wire to see the voltage bot.right. I chose 4.5k as the 1st. But you can scale this to 5V and reduce LED R’s.  Single supply for all , CMOS (?) type quad Op  Amps as long as Vin is satisfied by Vcm range.  Comparators need puulup

Comment: @andyaka never upvotes great designs

Comment: ..Thanks a lot for your solution and thanks you for the information you provided it, I want to vote " this answer  is useful, very soon

Comment: Here I converted my design to all 5V https://tinyurl.com/y2bxgz2j with 0.5mA source and 5V logic and CMOS quad OA's https://tinyurl.com/y2bxgz2j

Comment: @Tony, Your design is great and really deserves to be upvoted. I have complemented it by a few of my 80s inventions that solve the same problem but in a non-traditional way. They are not so precise as your design but are more original than the straightforward solution with conventional comparators, logic gates and transistor switches. I hope you will appreciate my ideas...

Answer (score 4):

### Spot 3-LED indicator

You can solve this problem by a [3-LED voltage indicator](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279016://) consisting of only two transistors, three resistors and, of course, three LEDs. It is based on the trick of connecting two LEDs with different threshold voltages in parallel (auto switching).

[image: 3-LED indicator]

Fig. 1. Spot 3-LED indicator.

### "Moving spot" linear LED indicator

**EDIT 1:** I was inspired to do this editing by the Tony Stewart's "never upvoted great design". It is really a professional circuit solution that deserves many upvotes... but I would like to note that it is still a straightforward design implemented by conventional comparators, logic gates and transistor switches. I want to supplement it with a few not so professional but inventive circuit solutions where all functions are performed only by the transistors and diodes themselves (I made these inventions in the early 80's). They are not so precise but original... and I suppose they will be interesting for you...

**1. LED auto switching.** The idea used in the spot LED indicator can be further developed in a linear (bar) LED voltage indicator - Fig. 2.

[image: Linear LED indicator - 1]

Fig. 2. Linear LED indicator with diode auto switching.

Here, the LED forward voltages are artificially increased by connecting ordinary silicon diodes in series. Thus the transistors turn on one after the other and connect the next LED in parallel to the combination of the previous LEDs and diodes. As a result, only the new LED remains lit.

**2. "LED jumper" between two transistor strings.** This topology is based on another idea - the next LED connects, like a jumper, the tops of two conductive strings of turned on transistors - Fig. 3. It reminds the topology of today's NAND Flash memory.

[image: Linear LED indicator - 2]

Fig. 3. Linear LED indicator with "LED jumper" between two transistor strings.

[image: Linear LED indicator on a breadboard]

Fig. 4. Linear LED indicator on a breadboard (*Young designer* BG magazine, number 3, 1983).

**3. "Lamp jumper" between two transistor strings.** This idea can be implemented with any indicators (e.g., lamps) - Fig. 5.

[image: Linear lamp indicator]

Fig. 5. Linear LED indicator with a "lamp jumper" between two transistor strings.

In this case, a "shifting" (Zener) diode is inserted between the input base circuits of the two transistor strings (the lower base rail is the input as in the LED circuit above).

### "Moving spot" 2-dimensional LED indicator

Finally, the LED auto switching idea can be enlarged to a 2-dimensional version - Fig. 6.

[image: 2-dimensional LED indicator_600]

Fig. 6. 2-dimensional LED indicator based on the LED auto switching idea.

I suggest to you to consider for yourself the circuit operation. It is based again on the "switching off" of an LED by connecting in parallel another LED with a lower threshold voltage. The LEDs are the same but their thresholds are artificially increased by connecting silicon diodes in series.

### **Edit 2:** 2-color LED indicators

Touched by Tony Stewart's gift (the attractive Falstad simulation in the link in his comment below), I decided to add more of my 80's inventions. Since I noticed that he used LEDs instead of ordinary silicon diodes, I remembered that I have variants of 2-color LED indicators. Here are two of them - Fig. 7.

[image: 2-color LED indicators]

Fig. 7. 2-color LED indicators.

Comment: This is quite sweet! Thanks for the link describing how you created this!

Comment: Cute,  https://tinyurl.com/y3foj3x4

Comment: @Tony, You are a real magician in circuitry... and Falstad is your "magic wand" with which you do your magic! Thanks for the effort, Cyril.